# Xcode SDK version issue which was uploaded from Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have received this email after uploading app to Apple/TestFlight.

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App name" 4.0 (37). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.2 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I uploaded the app with XCode 13.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get the correct email from Apple

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "App name" 4.0 (38). Your delivery was successful, but
> you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.2
> SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must
> be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or
> later.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App
> Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Comment: Please mark yourself as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same message on a bunch of builds. I have to assume this is an error on Apple's side since 15.2 is greater than 15 where I come from.

Given it's only a warning and doesn't prevent submissions I think it's safe to just ignore it for now.